# Com.sun.mirror Api is not present in java 8 tools jar

Tags: java, spring, java-8, java-6

We have developed some framework using java 6 and maven. Now we are upgrading that but when we change the dependency for tools.jar from java 6 to java 8 we are getting compilation error at AnnotationProcessorFactory because in java 8 tools.jar com.sun.mirror package is missing  which was in java 6 tools.jar.

Could you please suggest the way so that i can continue upgrade with java 8 .

What i tried :

I tried by adding apt-mirror-api-0.1.jar but that was not worked.

Please suggest.

Thanks,
Ganesh.

Answer (score 0):

For such issue I found two approach ,

1. Build com.sun.mirror using jdk 6 tools.jar by adding dependency in maven and keep rest
   for jdk 1.8 and during use in another project exclude com.sun.mirror in project
   dependency.
2. We need to go for latest version of Enunciate.
   https://github.com/stoicflame/enunciate/wiki/Migration-Guide

Welcome any suggestions.

Thanks,
Ganesh N.